# Autocompletion on variable with Anaconda does not show methods

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

Using Anaconda plug-in in SublimeText 3 I do not get available methods for a variable.
Should I expect this from Anaconda or is it not a feature?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10) # Autocompletion works fine

x. # Autocompletion does not show available methods
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - do you mean when you type `x.` that none of the methods show up, or do you mean when you type `x.mean().` that additional methods don't show up?

Comment: I mean that when I type x. none of the methods show up.